# How to extract a number if it's a single element in a json list?

Tags: python, json, rest

So I have a REST API that requests for the total number of requests made to the microservice.

```
response=requests.get("http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/_count")
r=response.json()
print(r) 
return r, 200
```

It is returning the number in the following format:
(say a total number of 8 requests were made)

```
[
    8
]
```

I want to extract the 8 from it and store it as an integer. How do I do that?

Comment: It's just a list with a single element. You can do `r[0]`.

Comment: That's not working. I tried it.

Comment: Not working how? What happened?

Comment: So it doesn't print either r[0] or wrong, and in my API log, I can't see this count api entry even though i executed it. So, it's not working

Comment: Well nothing in this code is printing or logging, so the issue is probably in other code you have not shown.

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
response=requests.get("http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/_count")
r=response.json()
print(r[0] if r else "something went wrong") 
return r, 200
```

**Upd.**

I've verified that this code working normally. I've set up proxy which respond `[8]` on each request and launched next code:

```
response = requests.get("http://www.google.com", proxies=proxies, verify=False)
print(response.text)
j = response.json()
print(j[0])
```

Console output:

```
[8]
8
```

So, it works.

Comment: There's no error message. Please refer to the above conversation

Comment: @marvelchick, it's not about this code. Error is on your side, check post edits.